# Angular JS - My scripts not working with UI ROUTER

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on web project with angular.
I use angular ui-router and .state() method.
I have javascript code into index.html( ) for to make datatable header into product.html

Javascript code in index.html:

```
<!-- For Table -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap progress js -->
    <script src="js/progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- icheck -->
    <script src="js/icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>


    <!-- Datatables -->
    <!-- <script src="js/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

-->

```
    <!-- Datatables-->
    <script src="js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>


    <!-- pace -->
    <script src="js/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var handleDataTableButtons = function() {
          "use strict";
          0 !== $("#datatable-buttons").length && $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
            dom: "Bfrtip",
            buttons: [{
              extend: "copy",
              className: "btn-sm"
            }, {
              extend: "csv",
              className: "btn-sm"
            }, {
              extend: "excel",
              className: "btn-sm"
            }, {
              extend: "pdf",
              className: "btn-sm"
            }, {
              extend: "print",
              className: "btn-sm"
            }],
            responsive: !0
          })
        },
        TableManageButtons = function() {
          "use strict";
          return {
            init: function() {
              handleDataTableButtons()
            }
          }
        }();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datatable').dataTable();
        $('#datatable-keytable').DataTable({
          keys: true
        });
        $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable();
        $('#datatable-scroller').DataTable({
          ajax: "js/datatables/json/scroller-demo.json",
          deferRender: true,
          scrollY: 380,
          scrollCollapse: true,
          scroller: true
        });
        var table = $('#datatable-fixed-heade').DataTable({
          fixedHeader: true
        });
      });
      TableManageButtons.init();
    </script>
```

Javascript not loaded and my table header not working in product.html
When I run this code without UI router my table header is working.
Please help me for solving this issue.